# Xamarin Forms ios assembly not found

Tags: c#, forms, xamarin, .net-assembly

We are building a xamarin forms project. In a xaml file we need to add a reference to a namespace to an assembly - Application.iOS (part of the same project).

xmlns:me="clr-namespace:Application.iOS.CustomControls;assembly=Application.iOS"

We have verified that the assembly name and the name space are correct. However, the assembly Application.iOS can not be found with the error:

Failed to resolve assembly: 'Application.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

We have checked the documentation but can not find what could be wrong.
What have we missed?

Comment: the shared Forms project does not typically have a reference to the iOS/Droid projects, because doing so creates a circular reference.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish at the end but a solution would probably come from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center

Comment: Hi, if you need to use a navitve control you could use Custom Renderer in Xamarin Forms. It will connect native control to Xamarin Forms. Have a lool at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers. If you only need to call a navtive method, you can check Cfun's comment to use a Dependency Service to achieve that.

Comment: @Jiang. Thx. Indeed this is what we are trying to achieve. We require to set the AttributedText of a native control (UITextView) in code. From the documentation we noticed that the shared project approach might not be applicable anymore - but we need to use dependency service instead. What we are still missing is how to connect the native control to the dependency service as there is no x:name property for this.

Comment: @Uli Okey, you could detail *connect the native control to the dependency service* about what things need to do. Then I will check that whether it's possible.

Comment: @Jiang.  Reason for the native view is the rtf functionality of the UITextView. We created the interface and used NSAttributedString(rtftext, new NSAttributedStringDocumentAttributes { DocumentType = NSDocumentType.RTF }, ref error) to resolve this. It is all set. One question remains though. We add the UITextView at run time in the platform specific code to the view (stackLayout.Children.Add(textView);) - what would be the best approach then to bind this native view to the viewmodel?

Comment: @Uli Okey, you also could have a try with [Effects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/introduction) to check.

Comment: Thx Jiang. We looked at this as well -however, the tricky bit is that we need to access the UITextView.AttributedText property which is ios specific. Seems we can not access it in any shared code as it is not inherited in the Editor in xamarin. So we are looking for some sort of workaround.

Comment: @Uli So have you solved that? If no you could share the tested code to discuss.

Comment: @Jiang, yes - all resolved. As we can access the shared object in the platform code we can set a property of this shared object to the rtf data (var rtfdata = uITextView.AttributedText.GetDataFromRange(new NSRange(0, uITextView.Text.Length), atts, ref error);

Answer (score 0):

As we can access the shared object in the platform code we can set a property of this shared object.

```
private void _uITextView_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e, RTFTextEditor rtftext)
        {
            NSError error = null;
            UITextView uITextView = (UITextView)sender;
            var atts = new NSAttributedStringDocumentAttributes();
            atts.DocumentType = NSDocumentType.RTF;
            var data = uITextView.AttributedText.GetDataFromRange(new NSRange(0, uITextView.Text.Length), atts, ref error);
            rtftext.Rtf = data.ToString();
        }
```